# Dapper : Mapper Query not getting values where as Dynamic Object Mapper Query does

Tags: c#, dapper

I am a beginner to dapper . I was going through the code and building samples . But I am having problems in retrieving data .
My code is as follows

```
 Console.WriteLine("Reading Values");
            string readSatement = "select * from employee where Id=@Id ";
             IEnumerable<Employee> objEmp1 = con.Query<Employee>(readSatement,
                 new {
                     Id = empId
                 });

             var objEmp2 = con.Query(readSatement, new { Id = empId });
```

In this code objEmp2 retrieves values from db for the id passed . But objEmp1 gives null values for the attributes of the object .

Employee class is as below

```
 public  class Employee
    {

      public int EmpId { get; set; }
      public string EmpName { get; set; }
      public int EmpAge { get; set; }
    }
```

Whats wrong with the code .

Comment: Do all the columns in the employee table in the database match the properties of the Employee class?  Because your where class has Id in it and that leads me to believe that your EmpId property doesn't match the Id column name in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure all your database columns either match the properties in your class you are using for the query or you return the columns with names that match.  For example in your query above, I believe you might want to write it like:

```
select Id as EmpId, otherColumn as Propertyname, etc.. from employee
where Id = @Id
```